# Convert json to java object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

What Jackson POJO structure will be required based on this piece of json ?

Something like ? :

```
class POJO {

    private List<ToAddList> toAdd;
    private List<ToRemoveList> toRemove

}

class ToAddList(){
String name;
int pos;
}

class ToRemoveList(){
String name
}


///////////////////////JSON///////////////////////////
    {
        "toAdd": [
            {
                "name": "test",
                "pos": 0,
            },
            {
                "name": "test",
                "pos": 1,
            },
        ],
        "toRemove": [
            {
                "name": "test"
            },
            {
                "name": "test"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Why didn't you try it yourself?

Comment: Looks like two lists of the same object type to me - but the objects in the `toRemove` list aren't passing back the `pos` attribute. What trouble are you having exactly with mapping this to a POJO?

Comment: @Perception I'm wondering if I'm on the right track, closest I found on the Jackson website - http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes is a very simple POJO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple bean with two fields, a String and a Number. This bean is used in lists, which are contained in another bean:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SimpleBean implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private Integer pos;

    // constructors, getters, setters
}

@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RequestBean implements Serializable {
    private List<SimpleBean> toAdd;
    private List<SimpleBean> toRemove;

    // constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Thats it.

Comment: Cheers, why do you implement Serializable ?

Comment: It generally good practice to implement data transfer objects as serializable, just in case you need to send them over the wire, using IIOP for example.